# Collection view in table view cell from nib

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview, nib

Can any one tell me , how can I use collection view inside table view cell from nib. I have Table view, custom tableview cell, collection view, custom collection view cell. Inside delegate method for tableview, I have added

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *cellId  = @"cell";

        CreateStoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray  *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CreateStoryTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        [cell.collectionviwStory registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell"];
        cell.collectionviwStory.dataSource=self;
        cell.collectionviwStory.delegate=self;

        // Configure layout
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0)];
        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];

        [cell.collectionviwStory setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

        return cell;

}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell";


    static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

    if(!nibMyCellloaded)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell" bundle: nil];
        [collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
        nibMyCellloaded = YES;
    }

    StoryPicsCollectionViewCell *cell = (StoryPicsCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Inside my Custom table cell

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 9, 10);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(44, 44);
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    [self.collectionviwStory registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
    self.collectionviwStory.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.collectionviwStory.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.collectionviwStory];

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.collectionviwStory.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
}

- (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.collectionviwStory.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionviwStory.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    [self.collectionviwStory reloadData];
}
```

Nit my code is crashing at

```
 StoryPicsCollectionViewCell *cell = (StoryPicsCollectionViewCell *)
[
 collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier 
 forIndexPath:indexPath
];
```

Crash Log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier StoryPicsCollectionViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ba6746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0182fa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ba65da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x0149c720 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x02a16f7b -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 1358
    5   UIKit                               0x02a172dc -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 160
    6   wedcraze                            0x00116f3f -[DashboardViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 127
    7   UIKit                               0x02a07d5a -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 258
    8   UIKit                               0x02a09e96 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4947
    9   UIKit                               0x02a0e6e1 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 281
    10  UIKit                               0x0238d57a -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 668
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01845771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    12  QuartzCore                          0x021b8e47 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    13  QuartzCore                          0x021ac925 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 403
    14  QuartzCore                          0x021ac77a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    15  QuartzCore                          0x02108c52 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0210a0e5 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 487
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0210a7fc _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01ac786e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01ac77b0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01abd1ea __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01abca5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01abc88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x046322c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x04632106 GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x022fa106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    26  wedcraze                            0x000f348a main + 138
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x07f60ac9 start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can any one help me with this? or suggest some tutorial for this

Comment: remove this line from tablecell     [self.collectionviwStory registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];

Comment: I tried that.But it is giving same error

Comment: I have updated..please check

Comment: remove this one also,    static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

    if(!nibMyCellloaded)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell" bundle: nil];
        [collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
        nibMyCellloaded = YES;
    }

Comment: when you register nib for reusable identifier you don't need to register either any class or load any nib. Because, dequeue method itself creates new cell object when queue is nil.

Comment: remove both (code in my first comment and other one)code blocks and try again. your code looks good.

Comment: make sure you have nib file present in bundle also.

Comment: I tried..still it is crashing

Comment: check your nib file , the parent view should of type IUCollectionViewCell or UIView .

Comment: yes...it is of type UICollectionViewCell

Comment: check reusable identifiers every where it should a single string all around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95346/discussion-between-user3575114-and-irfan-gul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place this code in awakeFromNib: of your Custom Table Cell

```
    UINib *nib = [[UINib nibWithNibName:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.collectionviwStory registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StoryPicsCollectionViewCell"];
```

Right now your deque call happens before you get a chance to register your nib. Try this hopefully it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still crashing